# Calculating the number of columns an image would use based on how many total images are available

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modulo

I'm using a custom 24-column layout of [Twitter Bootstrap 3.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/) for my page and I have a variable number of images I need to display.

My end goal is to have something like

```php
$images = array(
  array("image" => "<img src='...'>", "description" => "Desc 1"),
  array("image" => "<img src='...'>", "description" => "Desc 2"),
  array("image" => "<img src='...'>", "description" => "Desc 3"),
  array("image" => "<img src='...'>", "description" => "Desc 4")
);
```

displayed with the following structure:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class='col-md-8'><img src="..." alt="Desc 1" /></div>
  <div class='col-md-8'><img src="..." alt="Desc 2" /></div>
  <div class='col-md-8'><img src="..." alt="Desc 3" /></div>
  <div class='col-md-24'><img src="..." alt="Desc 4" /></div>
</div>
```

The logic is that I want to have at most 3 images on a row `col-md-8` and use `col-md-12` if only 2 will be displayed on that row, `col-md-24` for a single image.

I tried using modulo (`%`) for calculating - something like `$mod = 24 % count($images);` and `$mod = 3 % count($images);` but those are clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll need the number of images per row in multiple places, so put it in a variable so it can more easily change in the future:

```
$imagesPerRow = 3;
```

Let's first figure out how many rows you'll have:

```
$numberOfRows = ceil(count($images) / $imagesPerRow);
```

I'm using `ceil()` because the number of images might not be a multiple of three. If you have four images, `4 / 3` will be `1.33333...` which `ceil()` will round up to `2` to tell us we'll need two rows to be able to show all images.

Now we can create a loop that will render each row for us:

```
for ($row = 0; $row < $numberOfRows; $row++) {
    echo '<div class="row">';

    // we'll output the images here in a minute

    echo '</div>';
}
```

This is where things get interesting. Based on the current `$row`, we'll need to get the next `$imagesPerRow` images:

```
    $offset = $row * $imagesPerRow;
    $imagesInRow = array_slice($images, $offset, $imagesPerRow);
```

`$imagesInRow` will now contain 1, 2 or 3 images. We can use that to calculate the width of the columns for this row:

```
    $columnWidth = 24 / count($imagesInRow);
```

If there is one image, `$columnWidth` will be `24`. For two images, it will be `12` and for three images it will be `8`. If you someday decide you want four images in a row instead of three, then `$imagesInRow` can contain four images and `$columnWidth` may become `6`. Keep in mind that this will become a problem if you want *five* images in a row, because your 24-column grid is not a multiple of five and this will indicate a column width of `4.8` -- and there's no such thing as a `col-md-4.8` class.

So now that we have the column width and the (up to) 3 images we want to display, we can do that:

```
    foreach ($imagesInRow as $image) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-' . $columnWidth . '">';
        echo '<img src="' . $image['image'] .'" alt="' . $image['description'] .'">';
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

> Your sample array contains a full `<img src="...">` tag in `image` with a separate `description` that you seem to want as the image's `alt` attribute. That's a bit more complex and out of scope for the "how do I render these images in a grid" question, for simplicity's sake I assumed `image` would contain just the `src` attribute.

Putting this all together, your full script would look something like this:

```
$imagesPerRow = 3;
$numberOfRows = ceil(count($images) / $imagesPerRow);

for ($row = 0; $row < $numberOfRows; $row++) {
    echo '<div class="row">';

    $offset = $row * $imagesPerRow;
    $imagesInRow = array_slice($images, $offset, $imagesPerRow);
    $columnWidth = 24 / count($imagesInRow);

    foreach ($imagesInRow as $image) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-' . $columnWidth . '">';
        echo '<img src="' . $image['image'] .'" alt="' . $image['description'] .'">';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

See a demo in action at https://3v4l.org/1eTZd

Comment: Is there a way for all images to be all under just one `div.row`? I'm just about to get out of the office but I'll take a look at this in depth tomorrow.